# Find and add TreeItem to an existing node in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am trying to populate my TreeView with TreeItems, from a HashMap. Some of data carries the attribute "isProject" which means it's a project of a certain Client. I am trying to add these Project nodes to the higher Client nodes... But build a terrible feedback loop instead. Is there a better way to get a specific node (TreeItem) and add another one to it? Or a way to make this code work? Thank you!

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private void showTimeRecords() {
    ArrayList<TimeRecord> timeRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    ObservableList<PerformanceLogTableData> pflData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    TimeDataRecords rootValue = new TimeDataRecords("Client / Project", "", "", false, timeRecords, pflData);

    YearMonth setYM = YearMonth.of(2016, currMonth);
    root = new TreeItem<TimeDataRecords>();

    HashMap<String,TimeDataRecords> timeDataRecsMap = timeDataRecsBigMap.get(setYM);

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, TimeDataRecords> entry : timeDataRecsMap.entrySet()) {
        TreeItem<TimeDataRecords> node = new TreeItem<TimeDataRecords>(entry.getValue());

        if (entry.getValue().isProject()) {
             for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildren().size(); i++) {   
                if(root.getChildren().get(i).getValue().getName().equals(entry.getValue().getName())){
                TreeItem<TimeDataRecords> tempNode = new TreeItem<TimeDataRecords>(root.getChildren().get(i).getValue());
                tempNode.getChildren().add(node);
                root.getChildren().add(tempNode);
                }
            }

        }else{              
            root.getChildren().add(node);
            System.out.println(entry.getValue().getId() + " --- " + entry.getValue().getProject() + " --- " + entry.getValue().isProject());
        }
    }
    root.setValue(rootValue);
    root.setExpanded(true);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setEditable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prepending of project data in a LinkedList first.

```
LinkedList<TreeItem<TimeDataRecords>> entrys = new LinkedList<>();

for(TimeDataRecords entry : timeDataRecsMap.values()){
    TreeItem<TimeDataRecords> node = new TreeItem<TimeDataRecords>(entry);

    if(entry.isProject()) entrys.addFirst(node);
    else entrys.addLast(node); 
}

root.getChildren().addAll(entrys);
```